# Is there a way to communicate both "End of list" and "No items in list" with the same verbiage?

Tags: gui-design, lists

I'm trying to figure out good verbiage to simplify list rendering.

There are two cases I'm trying to solve within a scrollable list:

Case #1 would be communicating that the user has reached the end of a set of items

List

- Item
- Item
- Item
- You've reached the end of the list

Case #2 would be no items are on the list

List

- No items in list.

My thinking is that instead of solving this with 2 messages, "You've reached the end of the list" and "No items in list. ", there might be simple way to solve it with the same verbiage that communicates the correct context for both cases.

Some examples that come close are:

- "No more items"
- "All items are shown"
- "Finished fetching items"

But I'm wanting something simpler.

Comment: Are the items fetched synchronously?

Comment: "D-d-d-d, dat's all, folks!"

Comment: @Andy how do you mean?

Comment: Well there’s context missing to provide you with a suggestion. Why would it be necessary to end a list of items with an explicit message in the first place? It’s the scroll bar’s task to communicate to the user where the end is. If there are no more bullet points, there are no more items. If that’s not obvious to users, the visual design needs improvement. The _empty state_ of a list provokes the question of why it is empty? Can the user do something about it? Do you want them to create items? Import them? Change their search criteria?

Comment: My general advise: Don’t mix state messages. We already have problems with interfaces where devs reused the empty state message “No items created yet” as the loading state, irritating users when on a slow connection.

Comment: That's a good point about the scroll bar, maybe the context where an end cap is needed is when the list isn't long enough to display a scroll, so there's nothing communicating that you're seeing the full list.

Comment: Maybe the ideal I'm looking for is a single state to simplify the UI and reduce the number of views needed to maintain so that it's less likely a view gets broken because it was forgotten about.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of referring to the items, do it based on the list:

- List end

You can get to the end of a list whether there are items or not.